# Workbox precaching strategy

Tags: workbox

[From here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching), I figured out that:

> When a user later revisits your web app and you have a new service
> worker with different precached assets, workbox-precaching will look
> at the new list and determine which assets are completely new...

In order to figure out whether a new service worker is available, you would have to load the **.js bundle** (let's say, created with create-react-app built-in bundler), which means that the client would have to load the .js files **every time** in order to be sure that no new serviceWorker is present.

Which means, that there is not much point in caching .js files. Am I correct?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each navigation to a URL under the scope of a previously-registered service worker, the browser performs an [update check](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates). This entails downloading the registered service worker script file (bypassing the HTTP cache, ensuring that the response comes directly from the network), and comparing the fresh copy of the service worker script file with the previously installed copy.

If both the previously installed and freshly downloaded copy of the service worker script file are identical, then nothing else happens. That's what normally happens when users return to your site and you haven't deployed anything new. The only thing that gets transferred in this case is the service worker script file. The various resources that have already been added to the service worker cache don't get downloaded again.

If there is a difference between the previously installed and freshly downloaded copy of the service worker script, then the service worker update flow is started. During the update process, `workbox-precaching` takes care of comparing the precache manifest located inline in the freshly downloaded service worker script with the responses that are already in the cache. If there are any updates to the already cached responses—either because the `revision` associated with one of the existing URLs has changed, or because a brand-new URL was added to the most recent manifest—then `workbox-precaching` will fetch and cache those manifest entries for you.

Comment: Thanks! But what if my application code gets updated, but my service worker does not. Does `workbox-precaching` takes care of preaching if I use `workbox-webpack-plugin`?

Comment: If you include `workbox-webpack-plugin` as part of your `webpack` build, then each time your `webpack` build completes, an up-to-date precache manifest will be included in your service worker script. So yes, as long as you deploy the service worker script alongside the updated application code, everything should be kept updated.